# MapActivity を継承したクラスを作りたいが、インポートできない

Tags: android, java, android-studio, google-maps

Android Studioを使っています。
MapActivityを継承したクラスを作りたいのですが、com.google.android.maps.MapActivityがインポートできません。

マニフェストで以下の通り宣言し、パーミッションも追加しました。

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
```

File→Project Structure→Dependencies→play-servicesの追加や、Enter + Alt で find jar of Webというのを試しましたが失敗しました。

どうすればMapActivityを使えるようになるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.google.android.maps.MapActivity`（[Google Maps Android v1 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/v1/)）は2年ほど前に廃止されました。今でも動作するのかもしれませんが、新規にAPIキーが発行されないので、今から`MapActivity`を使ったアプリを作ることはできません。

`com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap`（[Google Maps Android v2 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/)）を利用してください。[導入方法](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro)は英語ですが、読めると思います。日本語の解説記事も多数あるかと思います。